# NoClassDefFoundError when using jfuzzy commands

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to run a fuzzy problem in eclipse, but i receive below errors. iam using jfuzzy

```
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sourceforge.jFuzzyLogic.FIS
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at com.example.trsa.RAP1$4.onClick(RAP1.java:182)
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-28 21:16:42.485: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 21:16:44.624: I/Process(721): Sending signal. PID: 721 SIG: 9
```

my FCL file is in res folder. the name of function block is heart and the output variable is angin
the code segment is

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
                // Setting the variables values

                EditText enteredrestpress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextrestingpress)  ;
                EditText choleserum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;
                EditText maxrate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextmaxrate) ;
                EditText restrate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextrestrate) ;

                String  strrestingpress = enteredrestpress.getText().toString();
                int numrestingpress= Integer.parseInt(strrestingpress);

                String  strcholeserum = choleserum.getText().toString();
                int numcholeserum= Integer.parseInt(strcholeserum);

                String  strmaxrate = maxrate.getText().toString();
                int nummaxrate = Integer.parseInt(strmaxrate);

                String  strrestrate = restrate.getText().toString();
                int numrestrate= Integer.parseInt(strrestrate);

                Log.d("taha", "Completed");
                Log.d(strrestrate, strmaxrate);

                ///// fuzzy calculation 


                try{


                    String filename = "/TRSA/heart.fcl";
                    FIS fis= FIS.load(filename, true);
                    if(fis == null){System.err.println("Cant Load File!!!");  Log.d("fuzzy", "loading complete"); return;} // error when loading fic file


                    FunctionBlock functionblock=fis.getFunctionBlock("heart");


                    // show 
                    JFuzzyChart.get().chart(functionblock);

                    //set inputs
                    fis.setVariable("chestpain", selectedchestpain);
                    fis.setVariable("restpress", numrestingpress);
                    fis.setVariable("serum", numcholeserum);
                    fis.setVariable("smoke", selectedsmoke);
                    fis.setVariable("sugar", selectedfasting);
                    fis.setVariable("restrate", numrestrate);
                    fis.setVariable("maxrate", nummaxrate);

                    // Evaluate
                    fis.evaluate();

                    // show output variables chart

                    net.sourceforge.jFuzzyLogic.rule.Variable  heart = functionblock.getVariable("angin");
                      JFuzzyChart.get().chart(heart, heart.getDefuzzifier(), true);

                     // print out 

                      System.out.println(fis);


                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("catch error", "error in fuzzy system");
                }


            }


        });
```

please help me to resolve this error 
thanks

Comment: make sure your java is updated version

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your : 
 `Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export` and put a check mark on the `Library`

[image]

Build the project and the problem should be solved.
I hope this helps.